# How do I set the x-coordinate in a swarmplot in seaborn?

Tags: pandas, seaborn, swarmplot

Trying to do a swarmplot with 3 different vectors in seaborn. I'd like to have each vector at a different x-coordinate and with a different colour.

Unfortunately all the tutorials have the data in some format I can't really find an explanation / manual for... This is what I've got so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn
import pandas as pd

# Create figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_ylabel('Evaluations')

colors = [
    'tab:orange',
    'tab:green',
    'tab:red',
]

labels = [
    'Method 2',
    'Method 3',
    'Method 4',
]

data = [
    [1, 2.1, 3.2, 4.5, 3.6, 2.7, 1.4],
    [2.2, 4.7, 5.1, 4.4, 3.8, 5, 3.4],
    [8.4, 7.2, 6.1, 5.4, 8.1, 7.4, 6.8],
]
data = np.array(data).T

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=labels)

seaborn.swarmplot(data=df, y='Method 2', color=colors[0])
seaborn.swarmplot(data=df, y='Method 3', color=colors[1])
seaborn.swarmplot(data=df, y='Method 4', color=colors[2])

plt.show()
```

This almost works, but plots everything on the same axis:

[image]

Also, the label should be on the x-axis not the y-axis. Pretty sure I'm missing something really basic here. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
df2 = df.melt()

colors = ["orange", "green", "red"]
sns.swarmplot(data=df2, x = 'variable', y='value', palette =colors)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, that gets them on separate axes, but still doesn't give them the colours I need